# bash parameter expansion search-and-replace capture groups

Tags: bash, zsh

When using bash-style [search-and-replace parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace) is there a way to refer to captured substrings in the pattern?

For example, I want to insert a leading `0` in filenames that end in "(**some digit**).mp3".  The files have other parens in the name, so I need to look for the close paren closest to the end:

```
${x/\(([[:digit:]]\).mp3)/\(0}
```

This doesn't quite work, b/c it doesn't resubstitute the previous end of the string.

Is there a way in bash or zsh to refer to the captured string? `$BASH_REMATCH` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Looking at the page you linked, it doesn't even seem possible to *capture* parts of a search, let alone reference them.  You may end up having to use `sed` to get the job done.

Comment: Do you want to prefix the **some digit** part or the entire filename?

Comment: The '''some digit'''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sed`

`sed 's/\(.*(\)\([0-9][0-9]*).mp3\)/\10\2/'`

I think that gets the desired functionality... I'm sure there is a slicker way to do it, I'm just starting to learn `sed` myself.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. ```mv "$x" "`basename $x | sed 's/(\([[:digit:]]).mp3\)/(0\1/'`"```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to first strip the extension from the filename leaving only the base filename in `name`. Next use the length of `name - 1` as the string index to return the last character in `name`. Lastly, check the lastchar against `)`.

```
name="${filename%.*}"  # remove extension from filename

if [[ ${name:((${#name}-1))} == ")" ]]; then   ## just isolates last char and test again ")"
    # modify as needed to insert '0'
    newfilename="0${filename}" # to append the '0' to beginning of filename
fi
```

Note: there is no need for a new variable `nefilename` that was just for illustration. It is perfectly OK just to add the `0` to filename with `filename="0${filename}"`

Comment: A bit of explanatory text would go a long way here.

Comment: Sorry, had to run pickup daughter at 4:00, I've filled in the explanation above. If you have any more questions, just ask. Good catch of the terseness of the answer :)